# Android: ListView detail paging

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-pageradapter

Here's my setup: I have `MainActivity` which has the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    FragmentList listFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);
        listFragment = new FragmentList();

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.list_container, listFragment);

        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

I then have `FragmentList`, which is a `ListView` fragment and `FragmentDetail`, which is the fragment displayed when selecting a particular `ListView` row.

Here's a snippet of the `FragmentList` code:

```
public class FragmentList extends Fragment {
    private ListView list;
    private FragmentDetail detailFragment;
    private long detailId;
    private ViewPager mPager;
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        // ListView gets set via an adapter

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                detailId = id;
                mPager = (ViewPager)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
                mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
                mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

                final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.list_container, detailFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
    }

    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            detailFragment = new FragmentDetail();
            Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
            mBundle.putLong("detailId", detailId);
            detailFragment.setArguments(mBundle);
            return detailFragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }
    }
}
```

And `FragmentDetail`:

```
public class FragmentDetail extends Fragment {
    private long id;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_view, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        id = bundle.getLong("detailId");

        // Set views based on id
    }
}
```

Here are my issues:

1. The line `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.list_container, detailFragment);` in `FragmentList` errors out saying that I cannot change ID of container. Why is that?
2. After I comment the line in issue #1 out, the detail fragment loads fine and lets me swipe. However, only one of the detail fragment pages contains any data; the rest are blank. How can I implement the following: say my ListView contains "iOS", "Android", "Windows" rows. When I click on "iOS", it brings up details fragment for iOS. When I swipe to the left, I want "Android" detail fragment to show up; then when I swipe again, "Windows" detail fragment, etc.

Thanks!